# Encoded images into H264 video are skipped and/or missing?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode images into an H264 MP4 video. The issues I'm having is that some of the images are skipped or at the end of the video simply missing. I need the video to play every single image I encode since it is an animation.

Any help setting the encoder properly would be greatly appreciated!

Encoder settings:

```
AVCodecContext *c;
...
c->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
c->bit_rate = mOutputWidth*mOutputHeight*4;//400000;
/* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
c->width    = mOutputWidth;
c->height   = mOutputHeight;
    /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
     * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
     * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
     * identical to 1. */
c->time_base.den = mFps;
c->time_base.num = 1;
c->gop_size      = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
c->pix_fmt       = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
...
av_dict_set(&pOptions, "preset", "medium", 0);
av_dict_set(&pOptions, "tune", "animation", 0);

/* open the codec */
ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, &pOptions);
if (ret < 0) {
    LOGE("Could not open video codec: %s", av_err2str(ret));
    return -1;
}
```

**Update 07/24/13:**
I was able to achieve a better video by setting the `gop_size=FPS` and writing the last video frame repeatedly `FPS+1` times seemed to resolve all issues. To me it seems odd to do that but might be something standard in the video encoding world? Any tips feedback about this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a set of images and you want to make a video out of them. If this is the case and you don't care about the size of the video, you can try to disable inter prediction. Maybe the encoder finds that some of the images are not required and skips them.

Inter frame prediction can be disabled by setting `gop_size` to 0.

Comment: Thanks for you reply... I have tried to look for that option but I can't find it. :/

Comment: @Jona Try setting the `gop_size` parameter to 0. This *should* disable inter frame prediction.

Comment: Thanks so much for that tip! It did resolve the issue however a few interesting things I noticed. 1. File size has increased about 6 times. 2. The last frame is not encoded? I can easily add a dummy frame at the end to fix that. 3. Encoding seems to take a lot longer.